# How to make a global object to access Excel Form controls

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I have this code for a global delete function:

```
Public Function delete()
    Dim ctl
    For Each ctl In add_form.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is msforms.TextBox Then
            ctl.Text = ""
        End If
    Next ctl
End Function
```

This code works, but just for accessing 1 form. I want the function to be able to access a global form. I tried to use `UserForm.Controls` but the output was just a debug with the text `"Object Required"`.

I am very grateful for any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? you want to be able to call this function from everywhere in the workbook but you can't?

Comment: yes, but just in the form of excel vba. not in the worksheets, cause i write this function in the module of ms excel vba

Comment: I don't know what you mean with the form of excel vba

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused with excel glossary.. i mean to be able this function to UserForm, look this image [link](http://imgur.com/9cUzXxT)

Comment: just add your code to the 'ThisWorkbook' sheet. then you can call it everywhere(also in userform codes) by typing: 'ThisWorkbook.delete()'

Comment: im sorry buddy, I mean is like an answer from mr rory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want this function to be generic, then you'll need to pass the form to it when you call it:

```
Public Function delete(oForm as Object)
    Dim ctl
    For Each ctl In oForm.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is msforms.TextBox Then
            ctl.Text = ""
        End If
    Next ctl
End Function
```

So if you called this from a form, you would use just `Delete Me`.

Couple of points:
1. The function could use a better name
2. Since you're not returning a value, you would normally use a sub rather than function.

Comment: I have written what you teach, but I replace the function with a sub, and I try it, but i get not action

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: like your example "delete me" i use it in the command button.. so when the button is clicked then all of textbox in the form is clear. do I have to upload the file?

Comment: im sorry sir, your code work perfectly but with function not sub, my fault is when i replace function to sub.. thanks sir